# [ROS2] rviz2 and rqt do not shown published image

Tags: ros2, rqt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have created a Gazebo world with a camera and the image is publishing to a topic of type sensor_msgs/msg/Image. I opened rviz2 and rqt to see the published image. But both tools shown a empty image.

[image: RViz2]

[image: RQT]

When I run the `ros2 topic echo` command I see that image data is published.

To test it you can use the *gazebo_ros_camera_demo.world* from the *gazebo_plugin* package.

Is this a bug of rviz and rqt or is there a missing setting?

---

**EDIT:**

QoS are the the same by default. I ran the command `ros2 topic info -v /demo_cam/camera1/image_raw` and got following output:

```
Type: sensor_msgs/msg/Image

Publisher count: 1

Node name: camera_controller
Node namespace: /demo_cam
Topic type: sensor_msgs/msg/Image
Endpoint type: PUBLISHER
GID: 01.0f.0d.01.ba.44.00.00.01.00.00.00.00.00.12.03.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00
QoS profile:
  Reliability: RMW_QOS_POLICY_RELIABILITY_BEST_EFFORT
  Durability: RMW_QOS_POLICY_DURABILITY_VOLATILE
  Lifespan: 2147483651294967295 nanoseconds
  Deadline: 2147483651294967295 nanoseconds
  Liveliness: RMW_QOS_POLICY_LIVELINESS_AUTOMATIC
  Liveliness lease duration: 2147483651294967295 nanoseconds

Subscription count: 1

Node name: rviz
Node namespace: /
Topic type: sensor_msgs/msg/Image
Endpoint type: SUBSCRIPTION
GID: 01.0f.0d.01.99.45.00.00.01.00.00.00.00.00.26.04.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00
QoS profile:
  Reliability: RMW_QOS_POLICY_RELIABILITY_RELIABLE
  Durability: RMW_QOS_POLICY_DURABILITY_VOLATILE
  Lifespan: 2147483651294967295 nanoseconds
  Deadline: 2147483651294967295 nanoseconds
  Liveliness: RMW_QOS_POLICY_LIVELINESS_AUTOMATIC
  Liveliness lease duration: 2147483651294967295 nanoseconds
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/359390/%5Bros2%5D-rviz2-and-rqt-do-not-shown-published-image/) by [lmiller](https://answers.ros.org/users/48153/lmiller/) on ROS Answers with karma: 219 on 2020-08-13

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Phgo](https://answers.ros.org/users/45485/phgo/) on 2020-08-13**:
I tried to reproduce your problem in `eloquent` and experienced the same issue in rviz. However, rqt works out of the box for me. Looks like rviz requires the tf transform from your fixed frame to `camera_link` to be available. Try setting your fixed frame to `camera_link` or providing a tf transform.

Another common issue in this context are mismatching Quality of Service settings. However, it works fine with the default settings in my case. (not sure whether rqt's default QoS settings changed in foxy)

**Comment by [lmiller](https://answers.ros.org/users/48153/lmiller/) on 2020-08-13**:
Thanks for your reply. I have edited my question with the QoS.
I also tried to set the fixed frame in RViz to *camera_link* but I dont get it working

**Comment by [Phgo](https://answers.ros.org/users/45485/phgo/) on 2020-08-13**:
@lmiller you wrote in your edit, that the QoS settings are the same but your log output shows that your publisher is reliability `BEST_EFFORT`, while the subscriber is set to `RELIABLE`.
This is not a compatible configuration (see [here](https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Concepts/About-Quality-of-Service-Settings/#qos-compatibilities)).
Have you tried changing your rviz subscriber to best effort in the topic section?

**Comment by [lmiller](https://answers.ros.org/users/48153/lmiller/) on 2020-08-13**:
@Phgo Oh I didnt see that. I set the reliability QoS to `Best Effort` in RViz & the world frame to `camera_link` and now it works in RViz.

**Comment by [Phgo](https://answers.ros.org/users/45485/phgo/) on 2020-08-13**:
@lmiller as far as I know is not yet possible to change the QoS in rqt GUI (The [issue](https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt/issues/187) addressing this is still open)
Do you need any further help on this or does this answer your question?

**Comment by [lmiller](https://answers.ros.org/users/48153/lmiller/) on 2020-08-13**:
@Phgo Thanks this answered my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As @Phgo answered in the comments the QoS were mismatched. Also the frame in RViz was not set correctly.

The image plugin in RQT has no option to set the QoS (see in that [issue](https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt/issues/187))

---

Originally posted by [lmiller](https://answers.ros.org/users/48153/lmiller/) with karma: 219 on 2020-08-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [808brick](https://answers.ros.org/users/51297/808brick/) on 2021-03-30**:
Is there a reason why the fixed frame needs to be the camera link? Does that mean I would have to open another RViz instance jut to view my robot model / localization instancesfrom my base link?

**Comment by [lmiller](https://answers.ros.org/users/48153/lmiller/) on 2021-03-31**:
If you have a TF from your *fixed frame* to your *camera_link*, then No there is no reason.
In my Case i had not any TF to my *camera_link*

**Comment by [808brick](https://answers.ros.org/users/51297/808brick/) on 2021-03-31**:
Hmm, it seems it does not count "revolute" joints. I am able to view images using the link I joined to the camera using "fixed", but then that link is joined via revolute joint to my base, and I am not able to view using the base as my frame.

**Comment by [lmiller](https://answers.ros.org/users/48153/lmiller/) on 2021-03-31**:
Please open a new question if it doesnt work for you.
So other people can join the discussion and may help you. Dont forget to post all relevant stuff like ROS distro, Code, etc...

**Comment by [808brick](https://answers.ros.org/users/51297/808brick/) on 2021-03-31**:
Understood. Apologies for getting off topic.